# testing php laravel controller shouldReceive arguments

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, phpunit

I have a laravel model which uses ardent/eloquent. I am trying to set up tests for the controller in particular, storing a new model that uses the ardent model.

The method works in the app but I'm having trouble with my tests

I'm having problems working out how to mock the calls this method makes.

My controllers set up and the method in question is this one:

```
use golfmanager\service\creator\TicketCreatorInterface;

//controller manages the ticket books

class BooksController extends BaseController {

/**
 * Book Repository
 *
 * @var Book
 */
protected $book;
protected $ticket;

public function __construct(Book $book, TicketCreatorInterface $ticket)
{
    $this->book = $book;
    $this->ticket = $ticket;
}

public function store()

{
    $input = Input::all();

    $result = $this->book->save();

    if ($result) {
        //if book created then create tickets

        $this->ticket->createTicket($input, $this->book);

        return Redirect::route('books.index');
    }

    return Redirect::route('books.create')
        ->withInput()
        ->withArdentErrors()
        ->with('message', 'There were validation errors.');
}
```

And the methods used by the interface (TicketCreator):

```
public function createTicket($input, $book) {

    //dd($input);

    $counter = $input['start_number'];

    while($counter <= $input['end_number']) {

        $ticketDetails = array(
            'ticketnumber'=>$counter,
            'status'=>'unused',
            'active'=>1
            );

        $this->ticket->create($ticketDetails)->save();

        $this->ticket->book()->associate($book)->save();

        $counter = $counter+1;

    }
    return $counter;
}
```

**My test** is as follows:

```
use Mockery as m;
use Way\Tests\Factory;

class BooksTest extends TestCase {

public function __construct()
{
    $this->mock = m::mock('Ardent', 'Book');
    $this->collection = m::mock('Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection')->shouldDeferMissing();
}

public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();

    $this->attributes = Factory::book(['id' => 1, 'assigned_date'=> '20/11/2013']);
    $this->app->instance('Book', $this->mock);
}

public function testStore()
{
    Input::replace($input = ['start_number'=>1000, 'end_number'=>1010, 'assigned_date'=>'20/11/2013']);

    $this->mock->shouldReceive('save')->once()->andReturn(true);
    $this->ticket->shouldReceive('createTicket')->once()->with($input, $this->mock)->andReturn(true);

    //with($input);
    //$this->validate(true);
    $this->call('POST', 'books');

    $this->assertRedirectedToRoute('books.index');
}
```

Currently I get an error:

```
No matching handler found for Book::save()
```

Is this being thrown because the book model doesnt contain a save method? If it is how do I mock the model correctly. I don't want it to touch the database (although it could if it has to).
Is it the multiple saves in the createTicket method?

Still learning how to set up tests correctly - slowly getting there but not enough knowledge yet.

If I change the name of the method in shouldReceive to say 'store' it still comes up with the save() error message.

**Update:**
I have isolated part of the problem to the createTicket call. I've changed my testStore test and updated as above.

My error with this current test is: `Undefined index: start_number`.

If I remove the call to createTicket in the controller method I don't get an error. I tried using Input::replace to replace the input from a form but appears not getting through to my function

How can I simulate a form input in the mocked objects?

Thanks